# Mocking concat functions in PHPUnit

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

I am trying to mock the following line:

```
$this->entity_manager->getRepository('Bundle:Core')->getActive();
```

how can I mock this line?
I know that you can mock the getRespository like that:

```
$entityManagerStub = $this->getMockBuilder('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager')->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();
$entityManagerStub->method('getRepository')->with('Bundle:Core');
```

but how can I mock also the getActive function?
will something like that can work?

```
$entityManagerStub->method('getRepository')->method('getActive')->with('Example');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**POST EDITED WITH NEW SOLUTION**

*new library to handle mock issues made my life much easier:*
https://github.com/danrevah/ShortifyPunit

```
$entityManagerStub = ShortifyPunit::mock('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');

ShortifyPunit::when($entityManagerStub)->getRepository('Bundle:Core')->
               getActive()->returns($mockingResponse);
```